# Google Script: My time-based trigger is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I made this trigger and I let it run for a couple days but it hasn't worked yet.
My function is fairly simple: there's a button that can be pressed at any time but I also want it to run/be pressed every night at 11:59 PM.
Here's the function:

```
// Triggers 'Move to Custom Report' button every 24 hours
// Runs at approximately 23:59 am in the timezone of the script
function triggerCustomReportButton(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendToCustomReportSheet")
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(23)
  .nearMinute(59)
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}
```

"sendToCustomReportSheet" is the function that is run after pressing the button.
Thanks

Comment: Check your executions and see if there's any failures. What's the code for `sendToCustomReportSheet`? Take a look at this [mcve].

Comment: Why not simply install sendToCustomReportSheet as a time based trigger?  How is triggerCustomReportButton defined as a trigger?